# ZFS, NFS and Nexenta

Tags: zfs, nexenta, nfs

Is this message familiar to someone ?

---

```
zfs-clu-01a rpcmod: [ID 851375 kern.warning] WARNING: svc_cots_kdup no slots 
free
zfs-clu-01a last message repeated 75220 times
```

---

We have a lot of trouble using NFS on ZFS .
Actually we cannot copy big files (>500mo) over NFS and we have performance 
issues.

```
NFS client using NFSv3 over TCP

**--NFS Server Configuration :**

Concurrent NFSD Servers: 4096
NFSD queue length: 512
Concurrent LOCKD Servers: 4096
LOCKD queue length 512

**-- System configuration** 

**1/ Disable ZIL**
Settings -> Preferences -> System
Sys_zfs_nocacheflush            Yes (default: No)
Warning: it is unsafe without UPS

**2/Disable Nagel algoritm**
Settings -> Preferences -> Network
Net_tcp_naglim_def              1 (default: 4095)

**4/ disable sync**
Data Management -> Shares -> Folder xxx
Sync      disable (default: Standard)
```

I can provide more information if required.

**-------- UPDATE 01 -------------**

I have a new interesting thing :

The problem is only or most seen with "centos" system ( release 6.5 )

Same thing with Debian (last version) is working good on this file copy as the same time period

**Here is more information :**

```
    OS: Nexenta Ver. 31-5-0
    Load Average 1.25, 1.26, 1.21
    NFSv3 Server (configuration in my last email)
```

**1) NFS CLIENT**

```
    Clients Number: 15 with very high access demand  and then we have more than 20 others low access
    Centos 6 and Debian 7
    NFS Client v3
    Mout options :
    nfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,vers=3,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,proto=tcp,mountproto=tcp,nolock)
    Nics: 1x 1g
    Dedicated NFS vlan
```

**2) zpool list**

```
    NAME     SIZE ALLOC  FREE CAP DEDUP HEALTH ALTROOT
    syspool  464G 181G   283G 39% 1.00x ONLINE -
    tank1   6.52T 2.38T 4.13T 36% 1.00x ONLINE -
```

**3) zpool status**

```
    pool: syspool
    state: ONLINE
    scan: none requested
    config:
    NAME STATE READ WRITE CKSUM
    syspool  ONLINE 0 0 0
    c0t0d0s0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    errors: No known data errors
    pool: tank1
    state: ONLINE
    scan: resilvered 190G in 81h49m with 0 errors on Sun Jan 26 15:35:10 2014

    config:
    NAME STATE READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank1 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-0 ONLINE 0 0 0
        c6t5000C5005F0C34A7d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
        c6t5000C5005F1261CBd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-1 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005F531E2Fd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FD1677Fd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-2 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FD18BF7d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FD1907Bd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-3 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t50000394B820EA30d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FD1D133d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-4 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FD73F97d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FD7518Bd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-5 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FD7C2A3d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FDC123Bd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-6 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FDE1D13d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FDEAFDFd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-7 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FDEB127d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FDEB513d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-8 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FDF88CBd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5005FDF9C4Fd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-9 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C50067802A17d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C500678037A7d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-10 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5006780D6F7d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5006780DEB3d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    mirror-11 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5006780E90Fd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
            c6t5000C5006780E99Bd0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    cache
    c0t1d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    c0t2d0 ONLINE 0 0 0
    spares
    c6t5000C5006BF8C91Fd0 AVAIL
    errors: No known data errors
```

**4) hddisco**

```
    =c6t5000C5006BF8C91Fd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 37
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS08
    serial S0M19QGA
    guid 5000c5006bf8c91f
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5006bf8c91f
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006bf8c91d
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006bf8c91e
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005F531E2Fd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 26
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M04DCN
    guid 5000c5005f531e2f
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005f531e2f
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005f531e2d
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005f531e2e
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FDEAFDFd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 27
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M061KF
    guid 5000c5005fdeafdf
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fdeafdf
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdeafdd
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdeafde
    P end
    =c6t5000C5006780E90Fd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 29
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M06GV9
    guid 5000c5006780e90f
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5006780e90f
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780e90d
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780e90e
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FD1677Fd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 28
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M05WCR
    guid 5000c5005fd1677f
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fd1677f
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd1677d
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd1677e
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FDF9C4Fd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 30
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M03SZR
    guid 5000c5005fdf9c4f
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fdf9c4f
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdf9c4d
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdf9c4e
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FD7518Bd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 25
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M06JCM
    guid 5000c5005fd7518b
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fd7518b
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd75189
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd7518a
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005F1261CBd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 24
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M03LZY
    guid 5000c5005f1261cb
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005f1261cb
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005f1261c9
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005f1261ca
    P end
    =c6t5000C5006780E99Bd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 20
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M06GV8
    guid 5000c5006780e99b
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5006780e99b
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780e999
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780e99a
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FD1907Bd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 23
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M0657D
    guid 5000c5005fd1907b
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fd1907b
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd19079
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd1907a
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FDF88CBd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 22
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M04CQ7
    guid 5000c5005fdf88cb
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fdf88cb
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdf88c9
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdf88ca
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FDC123Bd0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 21
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M05WMD
    guid 5000c5005fdc123b
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fdc123b
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdc1239
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdc123a
    P end
    =c6t5000C5006780D6F7d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 19
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M05TVK
    guid 5000c5006780d6f7
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5006780d6f7
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780d6f5
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780d6f6
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FDEB127d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 13
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M061JX
    guid 5000c5005fdeb127
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fdeb127
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdeb125
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdeb126
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FD73F97d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 16
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M06J86
    guid 5000c5005fd73f97
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fd73f97
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd73f95
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd73f96
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005F0C34A7d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 14
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M0405D
    guid 5000c5005f0c34a7
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005f0c34a7
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005f0c34a5
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005f0c34a6
    P end
    =c6t5000C500678037A7d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 15
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M03FNP
    guid 5000c500678037a7
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c500678037a7
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c500678037a5
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c500678037a6
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FD18BF7d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 17
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M0659G
    guid 5000c5005fd18bf7
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fd18bf7
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd18bf5
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd18bf6
    P end
    =c6t5000C50067802A17d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 18
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M03WJV
    guid 5000c50067802a17
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c50067802a17
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c50067802a15
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c50067802a16
    P end
    =c6t50000394B820EA30d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 32
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor TOSHIBA
    product AL13SEB600
    revision DE06
    serial 43L0A02HFRD3
    guid 50000394b820ea30
    device_id id1,sd@n50000394b820ea30
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w50000394b820ea32
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w50000394b820ea33
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FDE1D13d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 11
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M060LE
    guid 5000c5005fde1d13
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fde1d13
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fde1d11
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fde1d12
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FDEB513d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 6
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M061HL
    guid 5000c5005fdeb513
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fdeb513
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdeb511
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fdeb512
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FD7C2A3d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 9
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M06HG0
    guid 5000c5005fd7c2a3
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fd7c2a3
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd7c2a1
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd7c2a2
    P end
    =c6t5000C5005FD1D133d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 7
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M064EN
    guid 5000c5005fd1d133
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5005fd1d133
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd1d131
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5005fd1d132
    P end
    =c6t5000C5006780DEB3d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 10
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 600127266816
    size_str 558.9GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor SEAGATE
    product ST600MM0006
    revision LS06
    serial S0M060TL
    guid 5000c5006780deb3
    device_id id1,sd@n5000c5006780deb3
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled yes
    parent mpxio
    parent_instance 0
    path_count 2
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 5
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780deb1
    P end
    P start
    P parent mpt_sas
    P parent_instance 4
    P path_state ONLINE
    P target_port w5000c5006780deb2
    P end
    =c0t2d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 34
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 511503761408
    size_str 476.4GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor DELL
    product PERC H710
    revision 3.13
    serial 0022d14c0cc2ee9e1900ac67e7a0a38c
    guid 6b8ca3a0e767ac00199eeec20c4cd122
    device_id id1,sd@n6b8ca3a0e767ac00199eeec20c4cd122
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled no
    lun_no 0
    parent mr_sas
    parent_instance 0
    =c0t1d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 33
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 511503761408
    size_str 476.4GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor DELL
    product PERC H710
    revision 3.13
    serial 0027a4060badee9e1900ac67e7a0a38c
    guid 6b8ca3a0e767ac00199eeead0b06a427
    device_id id1,sd@n6b8ca3a0e767ac00199eeead0b06a427
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled no
    lun_no 0
    parent mr_sas
    parent_instance 0
    =c0t0d0
    driver sd
    driver_instance 5
    device_type disk
    removable no
    media_present yes
    size 499558383616
    size_str 465.3GB
    caching_supported no
    vendor DELL
    product PERC H710
    revision 3.13
    serial 003f0f9308bb2c521900ac67e7a0a38c
    guid 6b8ca3a0e767ac0019522cbb08930f3f
    device_id id1,sd@n6b8ca3a0e767ac0019522cbb08930f3f
    is_ssd no
    mpxio_enabled no
    lun_no 0
    parent mr_sas
    parent_instance 0
```

Comment: If this is NexentaStor and you have support, this would be a good case for them. I'll reach out to see of any of their engineers can help here.

Comment: Way more information necessary. What does 'hddisco' say (as this is a Nexenta box), what does 'zpool status' say, what is in 'dmesg', what is the hardware in question, what is the network environment, what are the clients you're testing from, are you sure you're using NFSv3 and not NFSv4 (some clients default to 4), how are you attempting to copy files.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments. As we don't have yet the support licences for that system, I'm not able to contact them for help but it is an interesting case. The coast for a small non profit association is huge :) It's in our pipe .

Comment: @Givre Please take note of the username of the person who responded to you.

Comment: @ewwhite thanks, I had noticed . We are using the Community Edition of NexentaStore that is why I'm not able to contact them for any support.I tried the Nexenta forum few days ago but I did not get any answer :)

Comment: What sort of performance do you get on the Debian system?

Comment: It is likely very telling that it is only happening on RHEL/CentOS clients, but I'm afraid that's not a smoking gun for me - nothing jumps to mind. Have you tried asking on a RHEL/CentOS support forum/area? That the problem is not repeatable on Debian would imply the problem is not with Nexenta, but with RHEL/CentOS specifically.

Comment: Also, for the record, we have 1000's of RHEL/CentOS clients talking to NexentaStor every day and aren't reporting similar problems. Can you tell us more about your environment? Does anything differ between the Debian and CentOS machines, other than the OS? Hardware? Where they're plugged in/network environment? VM vs hardware?

Comment: I had a working test ! Using no mount option, it's working.. 
One I put any mount option, I have the I/O error, For example :
nfs vers=3,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,tcp   
With usually have nfs vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp and that was working grep until now . 
I don't understand what the system does to generate reach the error on NFS :(

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the problem appears when you override the defaults so that your r/wsizes are set to 4k? And that this only affects CentOS 6.5? If that's accurate, let me know, so I can try to replicate in lab.

Comment: Exactly, I cannot get any working configuration to copy a 1Go file over NFS if I try to override the defaults NFS parameter on client side. I'm pretty sure that was working before. Don't take to much time on that, if that was with all CentOS 6.5, you should have seen a lot of people in my case :) . Thanks you @Nex7

Answer (score 1):

Hmms, look like the system (Nexenta) is getting too many NFS connections or you're hitting a bug. You could try to up the maxdupreqs, that could be masking the issue, but let's try that first:

```
echo 'rpcmod`maxdupreqs/W0t4096' | mdb -kw 
echo 'rpcmod`cotsmaxdupreqs/W0t4096' | mdb -kw
```

To check what it's current value is use:

```
echo 'rpcmod`maxdupreqs::print' | mdb -k 
echo 'rpcmod`cotsmaxdupreqs::print' | mdb -k
```

But maybe it helps.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, thanks for your suggestion, Even with that values I still have the problem.  
rpcmod: [ID 851375 kern.warning] WARNING: svc_cots_kdup no slots free
Feb  9 20:16:36 zfs-clu-01a last message repeated 50370 times

I cannot explain why this does not happen with Debian but I keep getting an error with Centos clients.